# Issue parsing NodaTime LocalDate from standard pattern

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm having an issue trying to parse a string into a NodaTime LocalDate.  My code looks like this:

```
var value = "Monday, May 26, 2014";
var pattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("d");
var parseResult = pattern.Parse(value);
var localDate = parseResult.GetValueOrThrow();
```

This always results in an UnparsableValueException:

> Additional information: The value string does not match the required number from the format string "MM".

From what I can tell my value should conform to the standard pattern (when I look at the sample template value for the pattern, it looks pretty much exactly like the value I am trying to parse).  What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I changed my code to the following and am still receiving a similar error:

```
var value = "Monday, May 26, 2014";
var pattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy");
var parseResult = pattern.Parse(value);
var localDate = parseResult.GetValueOrThrow();
```

Results in another UnparsableValueException:

> Additional information: The value string does not match the required number from the format string "dd".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem here is that the pattern you're using is "dd MMMM" (in both cases), but your input is "MMMM dd".  (For "D", you also have the problem that the long date pattern doesn't include a comma before the year, which you have in your input.)

The following parses the input above, and also demonstrates how you can use `Format()` to debug the expected input:

```
var pattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
Console.WriteLine("Expecting input {0}.", pattern.Format(new LocalDate(2014, 5, 26)));

var value = "Monday, May 26, 2014";
var parseResult = pattern.Parse(value);
var localDate = parseResult.GetValueOrThrow();
Console.WriteLine("Parsed value is {0}.", localDate);
```

Comment: Incidentally, I think we could probably do a better job of reporting the problem here, so I filed https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=288.

Comment: Thanks Malcolm.  I would note that I ran into this issue because the default ToString() of LocalDate outputs the date in this format - is it intentional that this date isn't parsable by the built-in long date pattern? (Looks like it's missing a comma, as you said.)

Comment: It's not just that it's missing a comma: it also has the month and day reversed. `ToString()` is documented to use 'the' standard format pattern (it is actually "D", will clarify) using the _current_ culture, whereas you're parsing using the invariant culture.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they flipped their examples. The short date pattern (denoted by `d`) is "MM/dd/yyyy". You want the long date pattern, denoted by `D`.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I changed the pattern I was using and now I'm getting a similar error still.